# How to link accounts via API using the Auth0.js SDK in react

Tags: reactjs, auth0, account, auth0-lock

I am trying to set up a working example of linking accounts to my sample app. I am currently using the [react example found here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples) as my base. I have looked over the docs and the [example of linking an account with Lock](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-link-accounts-sample), but I'm not sure how to apply that to the react example I am working with. I have also looked at the [API for linking a user account here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_identities).

Here are the use cases I am trying to work around:

1. There would be a user who creates a new account on my site using Google. Then they decide they want to add another social login via GitHub to that same account. They clicks a button that allows them to login via GitHub and then it redirects back to their account page and they can now login to the one account with either their Google login or GitHub.
2. There would be a user who creates a new account on my site using Google. Another day they create another new account on my site using GitHub. Later they realize that they mistakenly made two accounts and want to merge them. They login to either account then click a button that allows them to login to the other account and then they are redirected back to their now merged account.

I think the API would be my best option, but I'm not sure how to obtain the `SECONDARY_ACCOUNT_JWT` OR THE `SECONDARY_ACCOUNT_USER_ID`. How do I get the user to log in to their other account? When I try to redirect to the login page when a user is already logged in it just redirects back to the page I have set to redirect after login.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there Camiblanch!

You could link the accounts together if they share the same email through a rule. Attached is an example that may help you in your quest. Thanks!

https://auth0.com/rules/link-users-by-email

Comment: Does the rule only apply to automatically suggest linking accounts? I looked over the rule and it seems like it will automatically suggest to link to accounts that share the same email address. My use cases are a little different than that